# Cannot style a LineString

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, openlayers

I'm trying to style a LineString, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my code:

```
function connectStationFeatures(feat1, feat2){
    var lineLayer = getLinesLayer();
    var point1 = feat1.geometry;
    var point2 = feat2.geometry;
    var style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        'fillColor':"#FF8C00",
        'strokeWidth':10,
        'strokeDashstyle':"dashdot"
    });
    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([point1, point2]);

    lineLayer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, {styleMap:style})]);
}
```

Alternatively I tried:

```
function connectStationFeatures(feat1, feat2){
    var lineLayer = getLinesLayer();
    var point1 = feat1.geometry;
    var point2 = feat2.geometry;
    var style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        'fillColor':"#FF8C00",
        'strokeWidth':10,
        'strokeDashstyle':"dashdot"
    });
    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([point1, point2]);
    var lineFeat = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line);
    lineFeat.styleMap = style;
    lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeat]);
 }
```

Any help is greately appreciated! THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add StyleMap to layer, not to feature

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Foo', {styleMap: style});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HqQ6V/

There are several different ways to define style - with hash, Style or StyleMap objects; you can attatch them to feature or to layer. This is quite good explanation: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html